# URL amigável com HTACCESS

Tags: htaccess, url, querystring

Estou fazendo meu sistema que irá usar URL amigavel com htaccess, só que estou com uma dúvida/problema. O meu HTACCESS é o seguinte:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Ele funciona quando eu acesso algo como **www.meusite.com.br/cadastro** só que eu tenho outra URL que tenho que acessar como a URL acima, só que desse jeito **www.meusite.com.br/visualizar/ficha/6**

VISUALIZAR = visualizar.php
FICHA = categoria
6 = ID

Preciso passar esses dados para o arquivo visualizar.php que está na pasta **pages**

Comment: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas/

Comment: de uma olhada nesse link... a explicação é bem completa

Answer (score 1):

O cenário ideal é você concentrar o roteamento na própria aplicação, deixando-a mais flexível e dinâmica, além de simplificar os redirecionamentos no webserver.

De qualquer forma para excetuar a regra que encaminha todos os acessos para arquivos e diretórios inexistentes, você pode adicionar a linha abaixo antes da última:

```
RewriteRule ^visualizar/ficha/([0-9]+)$ pages/visualizar.php?categoria=$1
```

Comment: no lugar "ficha/" eu tb tenho que enviar para o arquivo visualizar.php pois irá ser dinamico e não só ficha. Como fazeria isso?

Comment: É utilizado expressão regular no RewriteRule, então você pode especificar múltiplas regras, exemplo: `RewriteRule ^visualizar/(ficha|opcao2|opcao3)/([0-9]+)$ pages/visualizar.php?categoria=$1&id=$2` onde neste caso você informaria em categoria as opções "ficha", "opcao2" e "opcao3", ou pode substituir por "([a-z]+)" para permitir qualquer texto minúsculo.

Comment: Eu coloquei o que você mandou e está executando a ultima linha somente que seria RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 e não executa a que vc mandou, sendo que coloquei ela em primeiro no htaccess

Comment: Como você não utiliza RewriteBase, acrescente o caractere "/"  antes de "visualizar": `RewriteRule ^/visualizar/(ficha|opcao2|opcao3)/([0-9]+)$ pages/visualizar.php?categoria=$1&id=$2`

Comment: está dando a mesma coisa ainda. Executando o ultimo comando e não esse. Estou utilizando assim **RewriteRule ^/visualizar/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ pages/visualizar.php?p=$1&id=$2**

Comment: E qual a URL que você está acessando?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/FJU/visualizar/fichas/6

Comment: Neste caso se o .htaccess estiver dentro de FJU, você pode utilizar `RewriteBase /FJU/` e utilizar o RwriteRule inicial, com ^visualizar... sem barra inicial

Comment: Continua o mesmo :/