# Como criar uma pasta para cada usuário em PHP?

Tags: php, html, blog

Gostaria de um exemplo de como criar uma pasta para armazenar os dados de cada usuário em php, por exemplo `www.facebook.com/nomedeusuario`

Imagino que na sequencia é salvo um index dentro dessa pasta e esse index é criado no momento do cadastro, com as informações do usuário como no Facebook. Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: Isso não é pasta. Isso pode ser melhor chamado de URL Amigável. O Facebook pode usar o `/qualquercoisa` para `profile.php?id=qualquercoisa`. Sim, ambos são acessíveis! Pode ver sobre isso aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25985/url-amig%c3%a1vel-com-htaccess, mas complexo, ou aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75963/url-amig%c3%a1vel-utilizando-htaccess/75970#75970.

Comment: Não é pasta é url amigável, [olha esse exemplo](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/criando-url-amigaveis-com-um-codigo-simples-e-funcional). E [leia mais aqui](http://wbruno.com.br/php/desmistificando-urls-amigaveis-com-php-e-htaccessapache/)

Comment: Uma outra maneira de fazer reescrita, sem usar `mod_rewrire` é passar as variáveis após o arquivo index.php, exemplo: `www.seusite.com.br/index.php/pergunta/resposta` e captutar a URL e separar tudo `explode()`  `"index.php/"`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer inclusive, se configurar o Apache (ou equivalente) para isso, não precisa nem ser index.php. Pode muito bem ser `http://example.com/noticias/esporte` - é o que eu faço normalmente. Não uso htaccess e simplifico o processo todo.

Comment: to ligado @Bacco!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quiser criar pasta, terá que definir um caminho ou um diretório onde as pastas serão criada e salvar em uma constante ou variável e depois pegar o nome da pessoa e para a criação da pasta, antes de qualquer ação verifique se a pasta já existe. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
$pathName = "C:\\php\\www\\pastas_user\\" . $nome_user;

if(!file_exists($pathName )){
   mkdir($pathName); //aqui ele irá criar a pasta
} else {
   $pathName .= time(); //concatena a pasta para gerar com um nome diferente
   mkdir($pathName); //aqui ele irá criar a pasta
}
```

Após isso é só gravar o diretório da pasta no banco de dados no registro do usuário.

Comment: Acho que ele se refere a pasta como sendo a "URL", como ele disse, igual ao facebook.

Comment: +1, pois apesar de aparentemente o autor quer ser outra coisa, respondeu a pergunta. Afinal, ele pode estar querendo o URL para mil usos diferentes, inclusive salvar arquivos de cada um em separado. (e se não for isso, outra pessoa que está precisando disso pode procurar por "pasta" e achar exatamente sua resposta)

Comment: Sim Bacco, na verdade eu procurava por essa "url amigavel" criada através do .htacess, mas aprender a criar a pasta também será útil para futuros projetos! Obrigado a todos!