# Criar pasta em php

Tags: php

Tenho que criar uma pasta no servidor online.

O arquivo que cria pasta esta em site.com.br/exemplo/arquivo.php

Preciso criar a pasta na raiz do site, exemplo: site.com.br/arquivos/nome_da_pasta

Mas toda vez diz que não existe o diretório informado. Acho que é por que não estou colocando a URL correta. Sei que se fizer mkdir(site.com.br) não funciona... como proceder?

Estou usando o comando  `mkdir("/public_html/filemanagerarquiv", 0777);`

o site esta dentro de public_html.

Comment: Coloque o código que você esta usando!

Comment: Editado amigo!!

Comment: Coloque o código PHP que você esta usando, existe alguma variavel que pegue a URL base do projeto?

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta, talvez ajude. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124407/como-criar-uma-pasta-para-cada-usu%c3%a1rio-em-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode tentar esse exemplo:

```
<?php

mkdir(__DIR__.'/arquivos/nome_da_pasta/', 0777, true);

?>
```

ou

```
mkdir(dirname(__FILE__).'/arquivos/nome_da_pasta/', 0777, true);
```

Observe que a permissão 777 permite acesso total a pasta, o que não é prudente em determinadas situações.

Verifique as permissões necessárias [aqui.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)

Comment: Opa deu certo...e como faço pra criar a pasta em um diretorio acima? como faço o "../../" ?

Comment: Opa legal, não esqueça de validar a resposta...

Answer (score 2):

Para criar em um diretório acima, basta substituir o "**DIR**" por "..", por exemplo:

```
mkdir('../arquivos/nome_da_pasta/', 0777, true);
```