# Como deixar a minha URL mais amigável?

Tags: htaccess

Tenho a seguinte URL:

> www.site.com.br/www/login.php

E eu queria deixar ela assim:

> www.site.com.br/login

Como posso fazer isso através do .htaccess?

Comment: Vinculado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25985/url-amig%C3%A1vel-com-htaccess?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: A lista de possíveis duplicatas é extensa... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amigavel

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

você pode usar o mod_rewrite para fazer isso.

1) criar um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do seu diretório do servidor;

2) escreva `RewriteEngine On` na primeira linha do arquivo.

3) criar uma regra para o redirecionamento da URL.

ex:
Sua URL: **http://www.seusite.com.br/site.php?id=1&cod=novo**
URL desejada: **http://www.seudominio.com.br/novo**

Seu arquivo terá a linha:
`RewriteRule ^/novo$ /site.php?ind=1&cod=novo [NC]`

Pode ser um pouco confuso de primeira, mas você pode achar mais informações sobre isso aqui:
http://www.uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/v2/hospedagem/como-utilizar-o-modrewrite-para-conversao-de-urls-amigaveis-em-minha-hospedagem-linux.html#rmcl

e aqui também:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Essa regra deve resolver:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^www/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

"Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados" logo abaixo:

- A flag **QSA**, informa que somente *Query_String* poderá acessá-las.
- A flag **L** (*last*) é um sinalizador para indicar que a regra atual deve ser aplicada imediatamente, sem considerar outras regras (ou seja, ela se torna independente).

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%C3%A1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess/86900#86900)

Pode testar ela [aqui](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: Podia citar a [fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86900/14262) =)

Comment: [Essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715235/htaccess-how-to-remove-part-of-url) também @MarceloBoni